# Where are the files of my /home directory?

Tags: filesystem, files

I have reinstalled my system after facing some crashing issues with my software. I have a separate `/` and `/home`

When I am running `df -h` I obtain:

```
root@sougata-SATELLITE-L750:/home# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        29G  3.8G   23G  15% /
udev            2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           402M  860K  401M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G   22M  2.0G   2% /run/shm
/dev/sda6       558G  182G  348G  35% /home
```

It shows me 182 GB used in the home folder but I can't find those files in the home folder anywhere. So then I run `ls -l /home`

```
root@sougata-SATELLITE-L750:/home# ls -l /home
total 96
drwx------  2 sougata sougata 16384 Oct 10  2012 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 30 sougata sougata  4096 Aug 16 11:27 sougata
drwxr-xr-x 54 sougata sougata 73728 Aug  9 08:31 sougatapc
```

Are those files saved inside the `/lost+found` folder?

Comment: Why don't you navigate through those specific directories? You have two directories, possibly with your files, check them out!

Answer (score 8):

```
ls -l /home
```

shows you that there are 2 users - `sougata` and `sougatapc`. Each of them will have sub-directories in them such as `Downloads`, `Documents`, `Pictures` etc., which you can list by, `ls -l /home/sougata`. Your files are stored in these sub-directories, most probably and are not lost.

To get a better analysis of your disk, use `Disk Usage Analyzer`, which will give you graphical view of the disk usage.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Ron for your quick kind response. So i installed this software from software center and run it to view the disk analysis. And yes surprisingly sougatapc (which was the old name before reinstalling) is present with sougata. sougatapc has all those files which i need to transfer to sougata and completely remove the sougatapc option. How should i do that??

Comment: If you prefer a GUI, just browse to `/home/sougatapc` in nautilus and copy/move everything to wherever you want. After that to delete the user , type `sudo userdel sougatapc` and remove the `/home` by `sudo rm -rf /home/sougatapc`

Comment: I just went to every individual folder from the analysis and copied them to my current user sougata. But can i remove the sougatapc option completely as i dont need that option anymore. How can i do that???

Comment: you have to delete that user by `sudo userdel sougatapc` and then `sudo rm -rf /home/sougatapc`

Comment: @user1456916 As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In the files application click on the `Other Locations` tab, in the bottom right corner. Then press `Computer`.
There are 2 options:

- Search the name of your username/name

  For example, I would search <`YoureSOStubborn`> and there should be a folder with a house on it. That is your home folder.
- Press the `home` folder and then there should be a folder with your username on.

  Basically, go to /home/<`Your Username`>